# How can I calculate exponents about negative values in python?

Tags: pandas, numpy

a = np.array([-40, -20, -30])

I want to calculate exponents about a.

My code is a**0.5

but I got the result.

array([nan, nan, nan])

I want to get results of complex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [322]: a = np.array([-40, -20, -30])
In [323]: a**.5
<ipython-input-323-8f2154f01f45>:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  a**.5
Out[323]: array([nan, nan, nan])
```

But if the array is complex dtype, it's happy to produce a complex result:

```
In [325]: a = np.array([-40, -20, -30], dtype=complex)
In [326]: a**.5
Out[326]: array([0.+6.32455532j, 0.+4.47213595j, 0.+5.47722558j])
```

Comment: or `a.astype('complex')**.5`?

Comment: The `scimath.sqrt` suggested in the other answer does the `complex` dtype conversion if there are negative values in `a`.  So it's just a convenience cover function.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
np.lib.scimath.sqrt(my_array)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.emath.html. Never knew it was a thing before.